# Yes/No prompt problem with adaptive card in bot framework V4

Tags: c#, .net, json, botframework, adaptive-cards

**Background:** I have used 3 to 4 adaptive card in project of Yes/No. Right now, I have hard code for Yes/No; but if in future, I use other adaptive card of Yes/No. Then, I will have problem as emulator will point to the same code.

Do we have any other way to differentiate between adaptive card buy passing value or ID along with it?

Please help me out its a blocker in my project. I tried many ways like but unable to do so.

I have hard code it as like this:

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "Yes")
{
  await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Good bye. I will be here if you need me. ", 
                                                  cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
  await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Say Hi to wake me up.", 
                                                  cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to say, so please provide screenshots of your issue and include the code for at least one of your Adaptive Cards, and **please link to any instructions you've been following so far**. Are you saying you want your bot code to only respond to submit actions from a specific card and ignore submit actions from other cards? What channel are you using?

Comment: Are you still working on this?